# wso2esb topic jms subscriber

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to make use of the inherent WSO2ESB topics to publish to a jms queue. I have created the topic and provided a subscriber URL of jms:/TOPICTEST?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue. When I publish a message to the topic however it cant be delivered to the queue. The log produces the following

"The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/queue?destination=TOPICTEST URL."

JMS is setup correctly to use activeMQ, I am able to deliver to queues from regular proxy services without a problem.

In addition, I cant seem to work how how to publish to the WSO2ESB topics, does anybody know what the delivery URL should look like? Its not clear from any of the documentation I have seen, they always seem to use the test client which comes with WSO2ESB admin console.

thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Example extracted from "Enterprise Integration with WSO2 ESB" from Siriwardena, Prabath:

```
<send>
<endpoint>
<address uri="jms:/emirates?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&amp;transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty=contentType&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp; java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue&amp; transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
```

Comment: Hi, I think you have perhaps both misunderstood. I am trying to use the inherent topics within the wso2esb for this example. I am able to publish and subscribe to regular jms topics on activemq without any problem. I want to be able to make use of a topics that is created in WSO2ESB and publish events to a jms queue instead of an HTTP endpoint as is described in almost all the examples. This is an example of a site I have used for reference [link](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/wso2-esb-topic-tutorial-for-beginners.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the following sample for your requirement.
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Publish-Subscribe+(Pub-Sub)+with+JMS

As it states you need to define the endpoint as follows,

```
<endpoint>
    <address uri="jms:/SimpleStockQuoteService?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=topic"/>
 </endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what you're trying to do, bit is it possible that you made a mistake in your config?

Instead of

jms:/TOPICTEST?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue

it should be for topics

jms:/TOPICTEST?transport.jms.DestinationType=topic